# Specified cast is not valid - List of double to list of float

Tags: c#, json, list, casting

So I store a list of float in a JSON file, this is what the JSON list looks like:

```
"RollSize": "[17.5,18.0,19.0,23.5,26.5,35.0,35.5,38.0]"
```

I use a method which returns a list of objects as there are multiple lists to return. I then cast the list of objects to a float. However the `Specified cast is not valid` receive an exception when doing this. But if I cast the list of objects to a double it works. Here is the two methods:

```
private void DisplayCutOffs(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try {
// Errors here unless I cast to double 
                _view.CurrentCutOffValues = _systemVariablesManager.ReturnListBoxValues("CutOff").Cast<float>().ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                LogErrorToView(this, new ErrorEventArgs(ex.Message));
            }
        }
```

Repository method:

```
 public List<object> ReturnListBoxValues(string propertyName) {
            if (File.Exists(expectedFilePath)) {
                var currentJsonInFile = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(expectedFilePath));
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(currentJsonInFile["SystemVariables"][propertyName].ToString());
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception("Setup file not located. Please run the Inital Set up application. Please ask Andrew for more information.");
            }
        }
```

However I noticed that if I looped around the list in a foreach I could cast each value to a float. So I'm not sure what's going on here.

Anyone know?

Comment: `"[17.5,18.0,19.0,23.5,26.5,35.0,35.5,38.0]"` That's a string not an array.

Comment: You're right, but it parses into an object list

Comment: A  double is 8 bytes while a float is 4 bytes.  Linq will normally produce a generic list object that can be cast to any type, but will not cast one type to another type unless it is explicit.

Comment: @jdweng So my cast is an implicit one?

Comment: Yes.  You are using .ToList() which is taking a Linq collection and converting to List<object>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're cast is casting from `object` to (the type), where (the type) is either `float` or `double`. This is an *unboxing* operation, and must be done *to the right type*. The value, as `object`, *knows what it is* - and this exception is thrown if you unbox it incorrectly (caveat: there is a little wriggle room if you unbox it to something the same size and compatible - for example you can unbox an int-enum to an int and v.v.).

Options:

- stick with `object`, but know what the data is and unbox it correctly - perhaps casting *after* the unbox, i.e. `float f = (float)(double)obj;` (the `(double)` here is the unbox from `object` to `double`; the `(float)` is the type conversion from `double` to `float`)
- test the object type / use `Convert.ToSingle`
- change the property to be a defined type in the first place, rather than `object`

Full examples:

```
List<object> actuallyDoubles = new List<object>{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
List<double> doubleDirect = actuallyDoubles.ConvertAll(x => (double)x); // works
// List<float> floatDirect = actuallyDoubles.ConvertAll(x => (float)x); // fails per question
List<float> floatViaDouble = actuallyDoubles.ConvertAll(x => (float)(double)x); // works
List<float> floatViaConvert = actuallyDoubles.ConvertAll(x => Convert.ToSingle(x)); // works
```

Comment: @Andrew I added some further examples below